Extracting Info.plist from HFS+ DMG on Linux (AlmaLinux 8) — 7z and dmg2img not working
I'm working on a PHP script (running on AlmaLinux 8) that needs to extract the Info.plist file from a .dmg file to retrieve the app version. Here's the command I use on macOS to locate the Info.plist inside the DMG:
shell_exec("7z l -ba -slt 'file.dmg' -r '*.app/Contents/Info.plist'");

This works fine on macOS, but when running the same command on Linux for DMGs that use the HFS+ filesystem, I only get information about the partitioning and not the actual contents of the DMG:
Path = 0.MBR
Size = 512
Packed Size = 52
CRC = 938EF024
Comment = Protective Master Boot Record (MBR : 0)
...
Path = 4.hfs
Size = 22016000
Packed Size = 3362869
CRC = 
Comment = disk image (Apple_HFS : 4)
Method = Zero2 2147483655 CRC
...

I also tried converting the DMG using dmg2img, but that resulted in errors:
Unsupported or corrupted block found: -2147483641
68.75%
Unsupported or corrupted block found: -2147483641
81.25%

For reference, I’m testing with the DMG from this URL:
https://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/client/installer/steam.dmg
I’m looking for a way to extract the Info.plist from DMGs that use HFS+ on Linux. Any advice on how to achieve this or alternative tools that can help would be greatly appreciated.​
